# results of Awk command different when executed from a tty versus a script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sh

I want to find line number of file by search word. Two variable, Start line and End line. Start Line must has word "COPY" and End line must has word "\."

When I try type command in stdout.

Find line number of "COPY" word.

```
-bash-4.1$ cat src_bakfile/merge_cdr_20130901.dat |awk '/COPY/ {print NR;}'
41
285
293
301
309
317
```

Find line number of "\." word.

```
-bash-4.1$ cat src_bakfile/merge_cdr_20130901.dat |awk '/\\\./ {print NR;}'
278
286
294
302
310
394
```

Results OK, correct.

But when I write to shell script and run. Results of find "\." is wrong.

```
-bash-4.1$ . test_cutbakfile.sh
Start Line ->
41 285 293 301 309 317


End Line ->
42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 286 294 302 310 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394
```

This is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

#-- Config --#
main_path="/home/hdmfec/ibank"
src_path="${main_path}/src_bakfile"

for bakfile in `ls ${src_path}`
do
    startlines=`cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/COPY/ {print NR;}'`
    endlines=`cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/\\\./ {print NR;}'`

    echo "Start Line ->"
    echo ${startlines}
    echo -e "\n"
    echo "End Line ->"
    echo ${endlines}
done
```

Why's stdout and shell script output not same? please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because command substitution (using `backquotes`) treats backquotes specially.  You will have to quote every \ again.  Or use $() command substitution, as suggested elsewhere.

This should work better:

```
endlines=`cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/\\\\\\./ {print NR;}'`
```

Comment: That's completely wrong, he just needs to quote his variables correctly.

Comment: It's still 100% wrong. The issue is not with that line, it's with his subsequent echo.

Comment: It's work. Most easy, but many backslashes is look like be complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Better just use `$()`. It's POSIX compatible. And quote your variables properly around `""`. Also, using `cat` is not needed.

```
for bakfile in $(ls "${src_path}")
do
    startlines=$(awk '/COPY/ {print NR;}' "${src_path}/${bakfile}")
    endlines=$(awk '/\\\./ {print NR;}' "${src_path}/${bakfile}")
```

Comment: @user919240 I hope you could already accept one of the answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes in your echo statements. Have your script like this:

```
startlines=$(cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/COPY/ {print NR;}')
endlines=$(cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/\\\./ {print NR;}')

echo "Start Line ->"
echo "${startlines}"
echo -e "\n"
echo "End Line ->"
echo "${endlines}"
```

**Without double quotes shell prints new lines as space since shell treats all individual strings as a separate argument without quotes.**

**PS:** You should also avoid parsing ls's output and use find instead like this:

```
while read bakfile; do
    startlines=$(cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/COPY/ {print NR;}')
    endlines=$(cat ${src_path}/${bakfile} |awk '/\\\./ {print NR;}')

    echo "Start Line ->"
    echo "${startlines}"
    echo -e "\n"
    echo "End Line ->"
    echo "${endlines}"
done < <(find "$src_path" -type f -maxdepth 1)
```

Comment: For your code suggest (while loop). It does't work for me. `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

cat: /home/hdmfec/ibank/src_bakfile//home/hdmfec/ibank/src_bakfile/merge_cdr_20130901.dat: No such file or directory
cat: /home/hdmfec/ibank/src_bakfile//home/hdmfec/ibank/src_bakfile/merge_cdr_20130901.dat: No such file or directory
Start Line ->



End Line ->`

Comment: Can you try: `find "$src_path" -type f -maxdepth 1` command on your command-line to see whether that works for you or not.